# How to link with intersphinx to django-specific constructs (like settings)?

Tags: django, python-sphinx

With a proper intersphinx setup, you can link to Django classes from your own documentation like this:

```
:class:`django:django.db.models.Model`
```

But how do you link to a setting? Django uses its own `:setting:` construct for that instead of something build-in like `:class:`. How do I link to a setting with intersphinx?

I've tried various incantations, but none work (and some are probably plain wrong):

```
:ref:`django:ROOT_URLCONF`
:ref:`django:root_urlconf`
:setting:`django:ROOT_URLCONF`
:ref:`django:setting:ROOT_URLCONF`
:django:setting:`ROOT_URLCONF`
```

Errors like `undefined label: django:root_urlconf` and `Unknown interpreted text role "setting"` greet me.

Comment: A way to extract the available link targets from an intersphinx objects.inv could help, too. It is, according to the file, partially zlib encoded and simple gunzip/unzip didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem: my local sphinx did not know about Django's custom sphinx roles, like `setting`. So a perfectly fine intersphinx reference like this:

```
:django:setting:`ROOT_URLCONF`
```

does not work until you've told Sphinx about the intersphinx target's custom role.

In the end got it working by copying a small snippet from [Django's sphinx extension](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/docs/_ext/djangodocs.py) as `_ext/djangodocs.py` next to my documentation:

```
def setup(app):
    app.add_crossref_type(
        directivename = "setting",
        rolename = "setting",
        indextemplate = "pair: %s; setting",
    )
```

And I added the following to my Sphinx' `conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys

...

sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "_ext")))
# ^^^ I'll do that neater later on.

extensions = ['djangodocs',
              # ^^^ I added that one.
              'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              ...
              ]

...
```

So: intersphinx works, but if you point at a custom role, you need to have that custom role defined locally.

Comment: It seems like you can also just define the setup(app) function directly in your conf.py and be done with it. (Without having to put it in a separate file, get it on the sys.path, and list it as a sphinx extension.) http://sphinx-doc.org/config.html#confval-extensions -- "The configuration file itself can be an extension; for that, you only need to provide a setup() function in it."

Comment: More recent link: https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-extensions

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the objects.inv for django to figure out what the correct cross reference should be.

It appears that:

```
:std:setting:`ROOT_URLCONF <django:ROOT_URLCONF>`
```

should work.

Somehow I have the objects.inv for django but can't find the URL I retrieved it from, in theory it should be https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/objects.inv but that redirects several times eventually resulting in a file-not-found error.

Comment: I tried your suggestion: no, still an "unknown interpreted text role 'std:setting' ", sadly. How did you come by that std:setting?

Comment: I dumped the objects.inv from django (https://django.readthedocs.org/en/latest/objects.inv). I have an embarrassingly bad python script that parses the objects.inv (https://gist.github.com/4118456)

Comment: One more thing: you need to make sure that the prefix in the link (eg "django") matches whatever you've listed in the intersphinx_mapping dict in conf.py, sphinx uses that to look up the URL and then retrieve the objects.inv from that URL.

Comment: `intersphinx_mapping = {
    'django': ('http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/', 'http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/_objects/')}` where `dev` is the latest development version or can be replaced by your version, e.g. `1.6`, the first argument is the url-prefix, and the second argument is the file to fetch the mapping from, which in this case requires an internet connection and is served remotely by a django app which renders the context of `objects.inv` only when queried.